# How to convert array to string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a array with one string value in it

```
["spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"]
```

How do i convert this to get `"spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"`

I tried using `[array].to_s` which converts to string but will not return the string element from that array.

Comment: You should be asking about how to get the first element of an array.

Comment: [Accessing elements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements) – being such a fundamental operation – is covered in virtually any Ruby tutorial / book / guide. And it's the same in almost any programming language. You could've easily figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take that one element out of the array:

```
["spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"][0]
#=> "spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"
```

Or:

```
["spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"].first
#=> "spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was thinking too much and did not look for basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous answers or just use the join method.

```
like this ["spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"].join, which returns

  # => "spec/main/fixtures/rules/test.yml"

 To know more about join
```

[ruby docs - join method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-join)